# How to check if the settings of copies in Apache IoTDB is successful?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I have set up multiple copies in the cluster version of Apache IoTDB. How can I know that my setup for these copies are successful? Anyone know what command can I use to check this result?

Answer (score 0):

You can `show variables` in Apache IoTDB and see if your copies appear in the query results. If they can been seen, then your settings should be successful.